# Utility to make Azure API calls?

Tags: azure

is there a generic, simple, easy and dirty utility ready to make Azure api calls like the next?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh360996.aspx

I just want to do it ASAP without programming it myself. Just enter the url and xml in some window and just send it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the **Composer** tab in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp). Simply choose the verb, enter the url, the headers and the body and you're ready:

[image]

Comment: But how would you compute the Authorization header? (Remember, he doesn't want to write code.)